# How to capture / upload videos at scheduled times

Tags: digital-recording, live

Let's say there is a conference and there are several hour-long talks by speakers.

Is there a way to setup a stationary camera that will

- Record specific talks (say the talks that start at 8:00a, 10:00a, 1:00p and 4:00p)
- Upload to a video hosting service(YouTube, ustream, livestream etc.)
- Never run out of space (because it records/uploads and deletes after successful upload)?

Is it possible to schedule recording start/stop times?If not, one should be able to start/stop recordings with one of those cameras that have wifi enable remote controls right?

Would live streaming be a better option since most video hosting services record the stream anyway?

Comment: With a computer and a camera controled by that computer you can surely do that.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to start livestreaming remotely(from the web - not from the same wifi network). I looked at the ustream mobile apps. I want to see if it is possible to mount a stationary tablet/mobile phone with an HD camera, connect to it remotely to start the ustream app installed on the device.

Comment: Then you should investigate that path (movile recording transfering video to computer)... For me the easiest way would be a compatible linux webcam that can be controlled via command line, that way it could be started/stoped from a script. Create a script to start/stop the recording at the specified times creating video files with date_time as name. After stoping the recording that same script would upload that file wherever I want and after a successfull upload delete the original file. If it has to be uploaded to a webpage (youtube) then wget might come handy.

Comment: I guess for me the sweet spot is to find a livestream ready device (like Panasonic HC-V250K or a tablet/phone with livestream app installed) that I can control remotely from the web. That is the simplest way I can think of to satisfy my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more I thought about my requirements the more I was convinced that I needed a wifi enabled "security" camera setup than an action cam setup.

I'm giving dropcam a try. It seems to satisfy all my requirements.

- Broadcast without any additional equipment
- Schedule recording times remotely from anywhere
- Broadcast is automatically recorded in the cloud for 7 to 30 days (subscription req.)

I just hope the video quality is good enough.